# How to prevent saving when cells are blank but to allow me to save the blank template

Tags: excel, vba, templates, save

I have a template that I need to send to various people in my company to use. Normally, half of them leave specific information I need blank when they return the form (despite multiple warnings from myself), so I set up a VBA macro to prevent them from saving the document until those specific cells are filled in. However, now I cannot simply save the template myself, and they wouldn't be able to save the template to their desktops either. Is there a way to do this or am I doomed?

````
If Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D34, E34, F34").Value = "" Then
Cancel = True
MsgBox "Please fill in the dimensions in cells D34, E34 and F34"
End If

If Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G34").Value = "" Then
Cancel = True
MsgBox "Please fill in the commodity weight in cell G34 "
End If

If Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J33").Value = "" Then
Cancel = True
MsgBox "Please fill in the commodity percentage in cell J38"
End If

If Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c22").Value = "" Then
Cancel = True
MsgBox "Please fill in the monthly bill commitment in cell C22"
End If

End Sub```
````

Comment: You could lock the sheet so no data can be entered directly in to the cells, then have a form that users complete which will require all input boxes to be complete before it writes the values to the cells, the VBA for the form would have to unlock and relock the sheet to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the macro on the event `Workbook.BeforeSave`
well described on [MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.beforesave)